Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen when npm start

task-manager@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start

Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
Require stack:


Delete node_modules and package-lock.json coz smtms they are corrupted.
use rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
Reinstall Dependencies
after deleting u can reinstall u'r packages.
use npm install
Check Your package.json
Ensure that ajv is listed as a dependency in your package.json. If it's missing, you can add it: use npm install ajv
Verify Versions
Sometimes, version mismatches can cause issues. Check if the version of ajv you are using is compatible with your project. You can specify a version by running: use npm install ajv@
5.If the problem persists, try clearing the npm cache: u can use npm cache clean --force
If you're using Create React App, ensure that react-scripts is up to date.
If you have installed ajv globally, it might interfere with your local installation. Make sure to use the local version in your project.
Sometimes, the error may arise from another underlying issue. Check the terminal for any additional error messages that could provide more context.
also ensure that you're importing any modules correctly. If you're manually importing parts of ajv, ensure that the paths are correct. after that you can reinstart your project. hope gonna help ya


using this code we can fix that issue

npm install ajv@latest


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
